# Flutter : create a custom reusable widget image

Tags: flutter

I try to create a reusable widget but some error happens...

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomLogo extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget showLogo(var nameImage, double radiusImage, double LeftPadding) {
    return new Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(LeftPadding, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          radius: radiusImage,
          child: Image.asset('assets/' + name),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I don't understand override and the "construction" of the widget, how I can use var in the widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a constructor to get values from where you are trying to call.

In following way you can create separate widget and pass arguments.

Moreover, here one mistake is left and it is hero tag. you are setting constant hero tag, which is fine if you are calling this widget once in a screen. if you are using this widget twice then it will not work because two hero's can’t have same tag in one screen. so, i also suggest you. to assign tag dynamically.

```
class CustomLogo extends StatelessWidget {
  final nameImage;
  final radiusImage;
  final leftPadding;

  CustomLogo({this.leftPadding, this.nameImage, this.radiusImage});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(leftPadding, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          radius: radiusImage,
          child: Image.asset('assets/' + nameImage),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How you can call or use this widget.

```
CustomLogo(leftPadding: 10,radiusImage: 5,nameImage: "hello",)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a code of an application, I have see on documentation that Hero is for animate an image on the same screen when I change the content of the screen, I can remove this ? Or it is good to keep that

Comment: Your welcome! if this work for you then accept my answer.

Comment: i didn’t understand your exact question can you elaborate more? @KealMlj

Comment: In the documentation about flutter, I see that “Hero” is for transition when I have the same image in two different pages. I can remove it if I use this widget for different image ?

Comment: you have to use different hero tag. there is no need to remove hero widget. specify unique hero tag to each hero's.  I mean tag: 'Sometihngunique'. for each hero widget.